# Angular - DialogRef - Unsubscribe - Do I need to unsubscribe from afterClosed?

Tags: angular, rxjs, unsubscribe

I got asked by one of my colleagues if we need to unsubscribe from the afterClosed() Observable of a Dialog.

We are using the takeUntil pattern to unsubscribe from all Observables on ngOnDestroy().

```
this.backEvent = fromEvent(window, 'popstate')
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    )
    .subscribe(
        () => {
            this.navigationService.backClicked = true;
            this.navigationService.navigateBackToDirectoryCenter();
        }
    );
```

ngOnDestroy()

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

So is it necessary to unsubscribe from afterClosed() Observable?

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
    (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        }
    },
);
```

or?

```
dialogRef.afterClosed()
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    )
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        },
    );
```

Comment: I have never unsubscribed from a dialog after it's closed and nothing has broken (yet). But nice question.

Comment: NO you don't need to unsubscribe, as it automatically completes.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

## No

You don't need to unsubscribe as the observable itself completes.You can verify the same by adding a finalize block to see whether observable completes itself or not.

```js
import { finalize } from "rxjs/operators";
```

```js
dialogRef
  .afterClosed()
  .pipe(finalize(() => console.log("completed")))
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

And when you will close the dialog, you will see `completed` in console, this depicts that **you do not need to unsubscribe the observable.**

Comment: Does it work the same way if you chain some observables using `switchMap`?

Comment: `switchMap` throws away the observable from `afterClose()` and takes over with observable from `switchMap` callback, which needs to complete properly.

Answer (score 9):

You usually want to unsubscribe from observables to prevent memory leaks and to prevent errors, when the subscribe block uses `this.xxxx` component property.

Even though the subscription completes and you do not need to think about a memory leak, you should be aware of the second problem.

The host component that calls `dialogRef.afterClosed()` might get destroyed while the dialog is still visible. The subscription would emit after close and when you access a component property inside the subscribe block, it would throw an error.

I think it's a rare situation, that the host component get destroyed while a dialog is active, but I wanted point that edge case.
An example could be a Floating Button that opens a Dialog but disappears after scroll or other circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Good question, just had a look at the docs (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) , nothing seems to hint towards the need to unsubscribe at all, what you already have should suffice.

Comment: I don't think the docs go into that much detail and unsubscribing might simply be outside of the scope of the doc. So I wouldn't rely on "if it's not mentioned in the docs, then it's not needed".

Answer (score 1):

You can test this yourself by setting the **complete callback** in the subscribe call. I tested this long ago to confirm what others here are saying; no you do not need to worry about unsubscribing. Testing for this is a good-know practice regardless.

```
observable.subscribe(
    (value) => { ... },
    (error) => { ... },
    () => { console.log('complete!'); }
);
```