# Angular Material Dialog: Does the component need to be manually destroyed?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-dialog

I'm using Angular Material Dialog and I was wondering if I need destroy it after the component is closed.

#### Example

```
openUpdateStatusDialog(alertId: string): void {
  this.dialog.open(UpdateStatusDialogComponent, {
    data: alertId,
    panelClass: 'ion-dialog'
  }).afterClosed()
  .pipe(
    map((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.updateNotificationStatus.emit(result);
      }
    }),
    untilDestroyed(this))
  .subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[AngularMaterial Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) components do *not* need to be manually destroyed after being closed.

Take a look at the official Angular Material [**Dialog Examples**](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples).

#### See Also

[Angular - DialogRef - Unsubscribe - Do I need to unsubscribe from afterClosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58198544/1164465)

Comment: This seems wrong. If I open and close the same dialog multiple times then any subscribers created within the dialog component remain active

Comment: @Ste See question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58198544/1164465