# .subscribe firing multiple times when modal is closed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code which opens a modal. When the modal is closed a call to `this.loadClientOccupations()` happens and information is refreshed.

```
  openAddOccupationComponent(servicePeriod: IServicePeriod): void {
    this.diaglogRef.open(OccupationAddComponent, {
      width: '25%',
      minHeight: '60%',
      data: {
        servicePeriod: servicePeriod
      },
      panelClass: 'no-padding-modal',
      disableClose: true
    });

    this.diaglogRef.afterAllClosed.subscribe(() => {
      this.loadClientOccupations();
    })
  }
```

What happens though is if you open the modal again and then close it, two calls to `this.loadClientOccupations()` happens. Open the modal a third time and close it and then three calls to `this.loadClientOccupations()` happens. This just keeps growing. Is there a way for me to limit these calls to just the first event? Is something not being destroyed that needs to be? This is the code that closes the modal.

```
  addOccupation(occupationDetails: IOccupation){
const occupation: IAddClientOccupationDetails = {
  occupationId: occupationDetails.id,
  servicePeriodSequence: this.data.servicePeriod.servicePeriodSequence,
  endDate: this.addOccupationForm.controls['endDate'].value,
  reserveClassType: this.addOccupationForm.controls['reserveClass'].value,
  startDate: this.addOccupationForm.controls['startDate'].value,
  clientId: this.clientId
};

let command: IAddClientOccupationsCommand = {
  clientOccupationInformation : occupation
};

this.clientOccupationService.addClientOccupations(command).subscribe(res =>
{
  this.dialogRef.close(occupation);
},(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  this.occupationEditError = new CarsError();
  this.occupationEditError.errorMessages = err.error.errors.ClientOccupationInformation;
  console.log(this.occupationEditError);
});
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `afterClosed()` method instead of `afterAllClosed`. Also, to avoid any memory leaks, you need to unsubscribe from the subscription. In your case use the `take` operator. So your code would become:

```
openAddOccupationComponent(servicePeriod: IServicePeriod): void {
  const diaglogRef = this.diaglog.open(OccupationAddComponent, {
  width: '25%',
  minHeight: '60%',
  data: {
    servicePeriod: servicePeriod
  },
  panelClass: 'no-padding-modal',
  disableClose: true
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
    take(1)
).subscribe(() => {
    this.loadClientOccupations();
})
```

}

Change your constructor to:

```
constructor(dialog: MatDialog) { }
```

Link to official [**documentation examples**](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples). Please check the code here for more information.

Comment: I'm getting core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: this.diaglogRef.afterClosed is not a function. Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 11

Comment: I am assuming that your `dialogRef` is of type `MatDialog`. This would be wrong way of doing it. Change the code according to my updated answer

Comment: dialogRef is of type MatDialog

Comment: Now I'm getting "Cannot find name 'take'

Comment: I'm dumb, needed the import. This works like a charm now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Faisal is it really necessary to unsubscribe from afterClosed()? it always completes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198544/angular-dialogref-unsubscribe-do-i-need-to-unsubscribe-from-afterclosed